# How to run Dropbox after it is installed with windows 10

Tags: dropbox

I have installed Dropbox but can't find any icons to run it. I have rebooted my computer but still no luck.

Comment: In the bottom right corner of taskbar (where clock resides) there is small arrow, click on it to reveal other icons.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have installed the Desktop App for Dropbox, you should see a folder in Windows Explorer:

[image]

You also should see a Dropbox icon at the bottom right side of the screen

[image]

If you do not see the icon, you may need to click the up arrow to show more icons. You can change your settings by clicking the click the Dropbox icon and then clicking the settings cog.

I hope this helps.